# Pattern Matching in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
--------------------------------
ModelName  |   Key  |    Raw_Key|
--------------------------------
Series 1   JKC VDQA      JKC-VDQA
Series 12  JKC-VDQAJ     JKC-VDQA
Series 3   JKCVDQA       JKC-VDQA
Series 4   JKCVDQA       MZQ-DWA
```

I want to check whether 'Key' follows the same pattern of that of 'Raw_Key'. 
So I wrote the following code for that.

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN Key LIKE 'JKC%VDQA' AND Raw_key<>'JKC-VDQA' THEN 'Error' ELSE '' END Message
FROM #Keys
```

But the code gave an output like this.

---

```
ModelName  |   Key  |    Raw_Key|  Message
-------------------------------------------
Series 1   JKC VDQA      JKC-VDQA   Error
Series 2   JKC-VDQAJ     JKC-VDQA   Error
Series 3   JKCVDQA       JKC-VDQA   Error
Series 4   JKCVDQA       MZQ-DWA    Error
```

Since 'Key' apparently follows the pattern. Why the Message column still shows error? I need an extra column hence I have case statement here. There are no leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: can you define pattern here? is it just that a space is treated the same as a hyphen and they have the same number of characters or do the characters need to match or...?

Comment: Confirm there is no trailing and leading blanks in `Raw_Key` and `Key` columns.

Comment: The only "issue" I see is that the last row shouldn't give you 'Error'. Does the `Key` for that last row contain any trailing spaces? Try `TRIM(Key) LIKE 'JKC%VDQA'` instead.

Comment: There are no leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: @scsimon Special characters and space are fine as long as main characters match.

Comment: You are sure that you wrote your example well, check it out https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=3a329cba9d408be4deba4ac71a5d0ed7

Comment: If that's the case, then you're probably going to need a nested replace or something to remove all spaces and special characters and then simply use an equality operator (=)

Comment: What is the data type of the `Key` column? Is it `nvarchar(x)` or `nchar(x)`?

Comment: @DavidG nvarchar

Comment: In that case you need to provide a [mcve] because as you see, the dbfiddle provided shows that your code works.

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is backwards:

```
SELECT *,
       (CASE WHEN Key LIKE 'JKC%VDQA' AND Raw_key = 'JKC-VDQA' THEN '' ELSE 'Error' END) as  Message
FROM #Keys
```